# My updatePanel don't update when I use the Update method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

My update pannel don't be updated when I use UpDetail.update() in my codebehind file.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpDetail" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="AAAA" runat="server"> LOL </asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %> </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in my cs file :

```
protected void GvGestionnaires_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                AAAA.Text = "TOTO";
                UpDetail.Update();
    }
```

My event GvGestionnaires_SelectionChanged is working but my panel is not refresh, why ?

EDIT :

I have try to use a button instead of my dx:gridview and it work .. why ? ! :o – user1594914 just now edit

SOLVED :

add EnableCallBacks="False" to my dx:gridview

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="GvGestionnaires" KeyFieldName="id" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource" EnableCallBacks="False" 
    OnSelectionChanged="GvGestionnaires_SelectionChanged"
    OnPageIndexChanged="GvGestionnaires_PageIndexChanged">
```

Comment: Try to put "LOL" as a value to the "Text" attribute

Comment: I have do it but it don't work for resolve my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer with new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Trigger to your Update Panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpDetail" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="AAAA" runat="server"> LOL </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %> </asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GvGestionnaires" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It don't resolve my problem too. My gridview is a dx:ASPxGridView (developper express)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the ChildrenAsTriggers="false" attribute and retest:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel  ChildrenAsTriggers="false" ID="UpDetail" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="AAAA" runat="server"> LOL </asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %> </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx .Update() is called BEFORE trying to set the value try swapping your code around in your .cs file like this:

```
protected void GvGestionnaires_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                UpDetail.Update();
                AAAA.Text = "TOTO";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put UpdateMode="Conditional" attribute inside < asp:UpdatePanel >

Answer (score 0):

LOL 
             <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>